# Get RegBinary Value as its Hex Equivalent using (Delphi XE5 )

Tags: delphi, binary, registry, hex

for some good reason i need to get a registry binary value as its hex equivalent. I found 2 good guide but i could not make it work. Hear is the registry key :

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\TestingSoft\Test Path\TestKey]
"Title"=hex:32,d6,bb,e9,b3,f0,9a,f2,37,64,65,ad,d6,c8,6a,75,9f,31

I need the exact hex char that are shown above.

I tried to read the binary and then convert it :

```
procedure TForm3.Button22Click(Sender: TObject);
var
TitleRegistry: TRegistry;
HexStringOfBinaryValue : string;
BinaryValue : Array[0..200] Of char;
begin
    TitleRegistry:= TRegistry.Create(KEY_WRITE OR KEY_WOW64_64KEY);
    TitleRegistry.RootKey := HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
    TitleRegistry.OpenKeyReadOnly('SOFTWARE\TestingSoft\test path\testKey');

    TitleRegistry.ReadBinaryData('title',BinaryValue,SizeOf(BinaryValue));

   HexStringOfBinaryValue := ConvertBinerToHex(BinaryValue);

   ShowMessage( HexStringOfBinaryValue );

   end;
```

how  I can make my **ConvertBinerToHex** function that returns me this string **32,d6,bb,e9,b3,f0,9a,f2,37,64,65,ad,d6,c8,6a,75,9f,31**  ?

Comment: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.BinToHex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with your code.

First, you are using an array of char.
In XE5, each char is 2 bytes.
And so each value in your array would hold 2 bytes from the binary registry value. 
This is not an insurmountable problem, but it would require your ConvertBinerToHex routine to separate the bytes from each char. 
Simpler, would be to use array of byte.
If you're still keen on using characters to represent bytes, you could use array of ansichar, which are one byte each, but why use characters when your intention is to read binary data.

Second, you're throwing away the length of the binary data.  Your ConvertBinerToHex routine has no way to know that there are any fewer than 201 bytes of data. 
The ReadBinaryData function returns the number of bytes read.  You need to capture that and pass it to your conversion routine.

Once you've done that, there are several ways you could do the conversion, depending on how important performance is, or how large the arrays are likely to be.  One would be to use BinToHex as suggested by David Hefferman.  The downside of that is that it generates uppercase with no commas.  If you need lowercase with commas, you could modify that result, or you could build the string directly.

If you want to keep it simple, the code below will do what you need.  It just loops through the bytes.  For each iteration of the loop, other than the first, it appends a comma. Then it calls IntToHex to get the two characters you need, and calls lowercase.

```
function ConvertBinerToHex ( const nBinaryValue : array of byte;
                             const nLength      : integer        ) : string;
var
  I : integer;
begin
  Result := '';
  for I := 0 to nLength-1 do
    begin
      if I > 0 then
        Result := Result + ',';
      Result := Result + lowercase ( IntToHex ( nBinaryValue [ I ], 2 ) );
    end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
TitleRegistry: TRegistry;
HexStringOfBinaryValue : string;
BinaryValue : Array[0..200] Of byte;
  aNumberOfBytes : integer;
begin
    TitleRegistry:= TRegistry.Create(KEY_WRITE OR KEY_WOW64_64KEY);
    TitleRegistry.RootKey := HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
    TitleRegistry.OpenKeyReadOnly('SOFTWARE\TestingSoft\test path\testKey');

    aNumberOfBytes := TitleRegistry.ReadBinaryData('title',BinaryValue,SizeOf(BinaryValue));

   HexStringOfBinaryValue := ConvertBinerToHex(BinaryValue, aNumberOfBytes);
```

For completeness, this is what it would look like using BinToHex. 
In this case, you could stick with using array of char, (or array of just-about-anything).

```
function ConvertBinerToHex ( const nBinaryValue   : array of char;
                             const nLengthInBytes : integer        ) : string;
var
  I : integer;
begin
  setlength ( Result, 2 * nLengthInBytes );
  if nLengthInBytes > 0 then
    begin
      BinToHex( @(nBinaryValue[0]), pchar(Result), length(Result) );
      Result := lowercase ( Result );
      for I := length(Result) downto 3 do
        if odd(I) then
          Insert ( ',', Result, I );
    end;
end;
```

Here's another version using BinToHex.  This one precomputes the length of the result, so there is no need to reallocate string values on the heap.

```
function LowCase(Ch: WideChar): WideChar;
begin
  Result := Ch;
  case Ch of
    'A'..'Z':
      Result := WideChar(Word(Ch) + 32 );
  end;
end;

function ConvertBinerToHex ( const nBinaryValue   : array of char;
                             const nLengthInBytes : integer        ) : string;
var
  I : integer;
begin
  setlength ( Result, 3 * nLengthInBytes - 1 );
  if nLengthInBytes > 0 then
    begin
      BinToHex( @(nBinaryValue[0]), pchar(Result), 2 * nLengthInBytes );

      for I := nLengthInBytes downto 1 do
        begin
          Result [ 3 * I - 1 ] := Lowcase ( Result [ 2 * I     ] );
          Result [ 3 * I - 2 ] := Lowcase ( Result [ 2 * I - 1 ] );
          if I > 1 then
            Result [ 3 * I - 3 ] := ',';
        end;
    end;
end;
```

Comment: Tank you very much for your time. My Problem was exactly here : **each value in your array would hold 2 bytes from the binary registry value** and i didn't use this variable : aNumberOfBytes . so I had couple of problems. Tank you again.

Comment: You might consider adding error handling as well.  What should your program do if the registry key or value does not exist?

Comment: I do ...  this was just a small part of my code ... tanks for your time